# VS Codeで設定を別パソコンに移動する方法

Tags: vscode

Visual Studio Code を使っています。あるパソコンで拡張機能や `settings.json` などを弄った後、他のパソコンでも同じような設定に揃えたいです。

Emacs や Vim だとドットファイルを共有することである程度設定を共有できますが、VS Code の場合はどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) という拡張機能を使う方法があります。GitHub のアクセストークンを渡すと、Gist に各種設定ファイルやスニペットをアップロードしたりそこからダウンロードしたりすることで、設定を共有することができます。

また、VS Code の issue トラッカーには、設定を共有するための仕組みを公式に提供して欲しいという [issue が立っています](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2743)。